# Django: got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make the DateField default as nothing. The documentation says to set empty_label="Nothing" but i get an error for that.

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Forms:

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    release_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_date'}, years=YEARS), required=False, empty_label="Nothing")
```

Error:
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`empty_label=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectDateWidget.empty_label) is a parameter of the [**`SelectDateWidget`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget), not the [**`DateField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField), so:

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    release_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
            attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_date'},
            years=YEARS,
            empty_label='Nothing'
        ),
        required=False
    )
```